# Should QT Block on int increment?

Tags: c++, qt

I seem to have an odd problem that every time i try to increment an integer that tracks the outgoing networking requests(the response requests will match that int so we can pair up response data). Well every time I try to increment the console will "block" and freeze at the incremntation? Is there any reason why it might do this? Its just a normal tracker_id += 1 code shouldn't be blocking and im usually am never noobish at these things.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you may get the impression that the debugger is on one line while indeed the code is stopped at the istruction before or after.

If `tracker_id` is a simple variable (e.g. `int`, `long`) and not a class instance then there is no way that `tracker_id += 1` is blocking. It's just impossible.

Note also that the compilers are becoming more and more liberal on how they translate source code to machine code, so be sure to compile with all optimizations disabled if you want to be able to track source code and variables correctly.

Comment: Good point, I'll check again, and see about disableing optimizations in qt some how.

Comment: I forgot about valgrind so I ran it, it immediately picked up where the program crashes at which IS the int... its claims that the integer isn't initialized even though i have it in the header file and I initialize it in the constructor part of the class it is in. So that is really wierd!!

Comment: With `block` I thought you meant multithreading blocking. `tracker_id += 1` can **segfault** and it's not uncommon if it's not a variable but a data member of an object instance and for example you're calling a method through a `NULL` or invalid pointer.

Comment: My mentor explained that the int wasen't working becuase the class i was calling didn't exist due to the way the running class was operating it apparently deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to classes in my main class, the first class is a simple networking class i created to easily call from an API (the Bitcoin JSON-RPC api so i could call just coin_server->getbalance()) the issue was that both classes were located in the main class and apparently the bitcoin class would be destroyed before it was set inside the game server class. There for it would explain why when i tried to call coin apis functions it would crash.